# Google Sheets notification triggered from function result

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I have a google form that populates a spreadsheet with a timestamp and two numbers.

For technical reasons I can't have the numbers passed directly into a database but they need to be copy-pasted individually.  I have a worker who does this daily (there are only 5-10 each day) and I'd like to get an email alert if the un-entered numbers exceed X.

[Spreadsheet with sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-PeOU7idxgncSLLff9-DRKquXZ3CxFtsagAjq6gMx80/edit?usp=sharing)

In this sheet, columns A, B, & C are filled by the form.  The worker, for each row, copies the formula in E down a row and then copy-pastes the result.  After the number is successfully added they write "Yes" in column F.

I know how to setup an email notification for any change in the document.  What I don't know and would like help with is how do I set up an email notification for a specific change.

For example, if the count of the number of rows that have values in columns A, B, & C but no values in F exceeds 20, send me an email.

Answer (score 2):

Once you are running code in the Sheet, you can loop through the column to see if the values you care about are set or not. You can then only send the email if your criteria are met. Keep in mind that if your logic is `if (empty > 20)` you will get an email on entry 20, 21, 22, etc. You may want to send one every 5 entries over 20 or something like that.